# CakePHP: Bind Model not working

Tags: cakephp

I have User HABTM Professions.
In user edit, there is a list of checkboxes of professions.
It was working when I defined the HABTM relationship in user model.
But as that relationship was interrupting other functions I removed it and put this in user controller

```
$this->User->bindModel(
        array(
            'hasAndBelongsToMany' => 
            array(
                'Profession' =>
                    array(
                        'className'              => 'Profession',
                        'joinTable'              => 'professions_users',
                        'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
                        'associationForeignKey'  => 'profession_id',
                        'unique'                 => true,
                        'conditions'             => '',
                        'fields'                 => '',
                        'order'                  => '',
                        'limit'                  => '',
                        'offset'                 => '',
                        'finderQuery'            => '',
                        'deleteQuery'            => '',
                        'insertQuery'            => ''
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

The return value of that binding function is also true.

Now when I call $this->User->saveAll($this->data), rows are not created in professions_users table anymore.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default behaviour of `bindModel` is to exist for one `find` operation, then revert to the default associations. You might think a `save` operation wouldn't trigger this, but if you use [Cake's count-caching feature](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count), or a Behaviour with an `afterSave` callback that performs a `find`, you might be wrong.

Try passing `false` as a second parameter of your `Model::bindModel` call. This will make your on-the-fly binding last the duration of the request. You can always explicitly reset the associations after your `saveAll` has completed by invoking `Model::resetAssociations`.