# CakePHP bindModel HABTM Save

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to create a binding from one model to my User model on the fly so that the JOIN is not called every time that I perform a find on that model. I am using the binding to perform a HABTM save.  However, when I use the bindModel function, the HABTM data is not saved in the database.

What makes this odd is that if I move my binding to the User model, then the save works perfectly. I don't see any indication in the documentation that the save behavior would be different when the association is made in the model versus the bindModel function (though, I may have missed it if there is any).

Here is my bindModel code in my controller:

```
$this->User->bindModel(
        array(
            'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
                'Othermodel' => array(
                    'className'              => 'Othermodel',
                    'joinTable'              => 'othermodels_users',
                    'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
                    'associationForeignKey'  => 'othermodel_id',
                    'unique'                 => true,
                    )
                )
            )
        );

if($res = $this->User->save($data)){
    return true;
}
```

And this is my user model.

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $belongsTo = array();
    public $hasOne = array();
    public $hasMany = array();

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Othermodel' => array(
        'className'              => 'Othermodel',
        'joinTable'              => 'othermodels_users',
        'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey'  => 'othermodel_id',
        'unique'                 => true
    )
    );
```

Again, I only have the relationship active in one place at one time, so I know the problem is not with the binding itself.  It seems the problem is solely related to the fact that I have tried to use bindModel.  Is this the intended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the responses in this article, it looks like the bindModel function only exists for finds.

[CakePHP: Bind Model not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266352/cakephp-bind-model-not-working)

Though there's no information in the CakePHP 1.3 documentation that states that the bind is only for finds, though that would explain the behavior...

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html

So, I am marking this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but are you sure you are not doing any other find operations between the binding and the save. `bindModel` only binds the model for the next find operation so you may need to pass `true` through to `bindModel` to tell it to keep the binding around.

Relevant links: [CakePHP: Bind Model not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4266352/569659) and http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/316c9796603eac57?pli=1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.  And I am sure that the save is the only operation that I am trying after the model binding. My code is exactly as it appears above. I've tried some other tests to make sure that Cake was creating this association, rather than building a dynamic one, through the debug function and, again, all looks ok but the save does not happen.  As soon as I comment out the bind in the controller and move to the model, then it works perfectly.  Wierd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$this->Message->bindModel(
            array(
              'belongsTo'=>array(
                'User'=>array(
                  'foreignKey'=>false,
                  'conditions'=>array('Npl.to=User.id '),
                  'fields'=>array('recive')
                ),
                'User_e'=>array(
                  'className'=>'User',
                  'foreignKey'=>false,
                  'alias'=>'User_e',
                  'conditions'=>array('Npl.from=User_e.id '),
                  'fields'=>array('recive')
                )
              )

            )
          );
```